# Vim: How to insert a column on the right side of a file

Tags: vim

I have a file like this, '¬' represents a line break.

```
aaaaaa¬
bb¬
cccccccc¬
ddddd¬
```

I know I can insert a column on the left in visual block mode and change it
to this,

```
eaaaaaa¬
ebb¬
ecccccccc¬
eddddd¬
```

However, is there any easy way to insert a column on the right at any specified column to make it look like this? Thanks.

```
aaaaaa              e¬
bb                  e¬
cccccccc            e¬
ddddd               e¬
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the simplest methods I could think of:

```
gg                  " move the cursor to line 1
A          <Esc>    " append the desired number of spaces and leave insert mode
<C-v>               " start visual-block mode
G                   " expand the selection to the last line
re                  " replace the content of the visual selection with e
```

This requires `:set virtualedit=block` and `:set nostartofline`. See `:help 'virtualedit'` and `:help 'startofline'`.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks, @romainl. `:set virtualedit=block` is the key. By the way, at the beginning, I had to make this work by using `3j` on step 4 instead of `G`. After reading the help, I know `G` doesn't work unless `:set nostartofline`(or `:set nosol`), because `G` moves the cursor to the start of last line by default, not keeps the same column, and then `re` will fill the whole rectangle with the 'e' character.

Comment: From the Vim help:
"Virtual editing means that the cursor can be positioned where there is no actual character.  This can be halfway into a tab or beyond the end of the line.  Useful for selecting a rectangle in Visual mode and editing a table." And `ve=block` means "Allow virtual editing in Visual block mode".

Comment: Ah right, I have `:set nostartofline` in my `vimrc`. Sorry for that.

Comment: Using `set virtual edit=all` is also helpful for this particular case, though that's not one you want to keep set (in your vimrc) but only enable it during such operations...

Answer (score 5):

A nice way is to do:

`:%norm A e` to append a space followed by an 'e' to every line in the file
(following your notation where `¬` indicates a newline):

```
aaaaaa e¬
bb e¬
cccccccc e¬
ddddd e¬
```

`:%!column -t` will get it all aligned by calling an external program to filter
the file contents:

```
aaaaaa    e¬
bb        e¬
cccccccc  e¬
ddddd     e¬
```

`:%norm $20i`  will shift the column of `e¬` more to the right, you could do
(that is for every line, go to the end, and insert `N` spaces before the e) to
insert 20 extra spaces:

```
aaaaaa                       e¬
bb                           e¬
cccccccc                     e¬
ddddd                        e¬
```

If the last column was more than one character wide, you could tweak the above
command like `:%norm $b20i`  (to move 'back' to the start of the word in the
last column).

If you want to do the above on only some lines of the file, you can simply
visually select those lines before hitting `:` and omit the `%`.

Comment: This is another smart easy way to solve the problem in OP, thanks @mattb. However I still prefer to give "Accept" to @romainl's answer, because `column -t` has some limitations. For example, if I already have a rectangle of n columns and not all cells are filled with a character, something like a sparse matrix, then I don't expect to use `column -t` to align the whole structure after I insert a (n+1)th column.

Comment: As for "how to control the amount of whitespace between 1st and 2nd column", just edit in visual block mode as usual, e.g. 1. gg (go to the 1st line) 2. fe (move the cursor to column e) 3. <C-v> (start in visual block mode) 4. 3j or G (expand the selection to the last line) 5. 20I<whitespace><ESC> (insert 20 whitespaces before char e in each selected line)

Comment: @gpanda, I was integrating your comment about how to add whitespace when it occurred to me another command line way of doing it. I put that way in since @romainl already covered it. As for dealing with sparse matrices, it's true that my approach wouldn't be the best (maybe you could introduce some temporary 'NaN' strings to allow the `column -t` to do it's thing, (and then doing `%s/NaN/   /g` but that might be more work than could be justified.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for doing this is like follows:

1. add sufficient spaces to the end of all lines to allow using visual block mode later:

   - `20A <ESC>`
   - `j.j.j.` ...
2. use visual block mode to insert the column inside the spaces
3. delete trailing spaces again (`:s/\s*$//`)